# Webform entity checkboxes not ordered as per source view

Tags: views, webforms

We are using the Webform module ( https://www.drupal.org/project/webform ) for an extended 'Contact us' type of form which allows people to select various options about a vacation they wish to take.

In this form the person is able to select a region globally and then are presented with a set of destinations falling within that region which are Entity Check-boxes which get thier values from a single view that combines data (The titles) of two content types (Destination and SubRegion)

Destination has about 15 results and SubRegion has only one (which is India).

Now when I view the view in preview mode the ordering is correct, India is listed between China and Indonesia.

When I view the output of the web form itself India is listed last and I am completely lost as to what is causing this.

I have tried rearranging the ordering of filters in the view etc to no avail, anyway I don't think the view is the issue because its listing the order correctly.

Is there any way to get webform to obey the source views ordering?

**Screen shot of view result in preview**

[image]

**Screen shot of rendered Entity check boxes**

[image]

**Screen shot of webform section holding elements concerned** (`which_destination_asia`)

[image]

Comment: Please see Issue #2890618: Rewritten view output is not used for "Entity Select" field 
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/2890618

Comment: @jrockowitz. Tried several of the patches without success. As we are so close to launch we have decided to put this issue on hold until afterward where we will be updating Drupal Core, then Ill apply the patch. Thanks for comment